# Dataset bias reduction for decision trees in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, decision-tree, text-classification

I have been working on classifying text and am currently using simple classifiers such as decision trees. However, I downloaded the dataset I am using from the internet, and it delivered results that are a little too good to be true.

I have a Pandas dataframe where one columns contains text, and another contains numerical labels. Using Pandas I have determined the most occuring terms for each label, resulting in the following (small part of the entire list)

```
true_frequency = [('trump', 5952), ('said', 3894), ('clinton', 3660), ('would', 1687), ('new', 1580), ('donald', 1498), ('campaign', 1466), ('people', 1442), ('debate', 1424), ('one', 1339), ('president', 1313), ('hillary', 1295), ('us', 1233), ('obama', 1077),.....]
```

and am attempting to remove these terms, which I put in a list called banned, from the corresponding data as follows

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in banned])
df["text"] = df["text"].apply(f)
```

I then revectorize the terms (CountVectorizer or tf-idf) in order to remove the top n terms from the actual data the classifier is trained on. However, no matter how many terms I remove, the accuracy trend always looks something like this:

[image]

Even the top 1000 terms are removed as a sanity check, but no matter what classifier I use, the accuracy stays the same. (The labels are classifiers, DTC = decisiontreeclassifier etc.)

**QUESTION 1**

Is there a way to remove the terms that influence the performance of the classifiers the most and retrain the classifier? (So the accuracy goes down)

**QUESTION 2**

If not, how can I determine what features to remove to influence performance?

Comment: i believe you can check feature importances for both decision tree and random forest? hence you could process data accordingly and retrain the classifiy

Comment: Good to know! I was not aware of the feature_importances_ of sklearn's decision trees. Guess I'll start trying things with those values.

Comment: This question is not really about programming, [DataScienceSE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for it. A few remarks: a performance "too good to be true" is not a realiable indicator of bias. Your model might be overfit, you should check by comparing the performance on the training set vs. test set. Generally in case of overfitting it would make more sense to remove the lowest frequency words. There might be a few other problems, like the use of accuracy if the data is imbalanced.

Comment: That point about lowest frequency words is a good point. I'll be sure to check try that out as well. Thanks for your input!